# Weak solution to the continuity equation which doesn't conserve the mass

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Is it possible to find a pair $(\rho, u) \in C([0,T]; L^{\infty}_{w*}(\mathbb{R})) \times L^{\infty}((0,T) \times \mathbb{R})$ such that $\rho \ge 0$ and in the weak sense, $$ \partial_{t} \rho + \partial_{x} (\rho u) = 0, \qquad (0,T) \times \mathbb{R}$$

but where \begin{align} \label{b} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \rho(t,x)~dx \ne  \int_{\mathbb{R}} \rho(0,x)~dx . \end{align} for $t>0$?

What I mean by weak solution is for all $\phi \in W^{1,1}([0,T] \times \mathbb{R})$ with compact support,

$$\int_{0}^{t} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \rho \phi_{t} + \rho u \phi_{x}~dxds = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \rho \phi(t,x)-\rho \phi(0,x)~dx. $$

For smooth solutions, the answer is definitely no because you can integrate the continuity equation (provided there is sufficient decay at infinity) to get the second equation. Does anything go wrong with $L^{\infty}$ solutions?

Comment: Is $\rho$ still $H^1$ in time or only $L^\infty$ too? And what kind of test functions do you want to use? Might be useful to include more information about the full regularity assumption you want on your solution as well as the exact weak formulation.

Comment: @stange Ok I will add that in. $\rho$ can be weakly continuous in time. The test functions can just be $W^{1,1}$ with compact support  in $[0,T] \times \mathbb{R}$ or $C^{\infty}_{c}$